# Is undefined behavior to declare a variable while passing by reference?

Tags: c

From cppreference:

> Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object must have
>   its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Code example:

```
int a = store_and_return_value(&a);
```

For both C and C++.

Comment: @t.niese If possible, I would like to know in both C and C++ :)

Comment: The concept of sequence points was abolished from C++ in 2011. The cppreference page needs to be updated. I am removing the C++ tag from this question but feel free to add a new question.

Comment: @Brian -- the **concept** of sequence points wasn't abolished; the **terminology** was changed. The intention was to preserve the rules that had applied previously.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree the intent was to preserve the rules that had applied previously, but the concept also did change to a more general one.

Comment: @PatrickJoséPereira *Re: "i = i++ + 1 is UB"* Until C++17

Answer (score 4):

This does **not** exhibit undefined behavior.

Section 6.5.2.3p10 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> **There  is  a  sequence  point  after  the  evaluations  of  the 
>   function  designator  and  the  actual arguments but before the actual
>   call.**  Every evaluation in the calling function (including other 
>   function  calls)  that  is  not  otherwise  specifically  sequenced 
>   before  or  after  the execution of the body of the called function is
>   indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called
>   function

So given your line of code:

```
int a = store_and_return_value(&a);
```

The call to the function `store_and_return_value` introduces a sequence point.  Assuming there is a line similar to `*arg = 123;` in the function, there is also a sequence point after this statement.

So any statement inside of `store_and_return_value` that dereferences and writes the passed in pointer is sequenced after `a` is formally initialized.  So regardless of what the body of `store_and_return_value` contains the program is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

`int a = scanf("%d", &a);` does not exhibit undefined behaviour.

These are well-defined steps:

1. An `int` variable is created on stack named `a`
2. `scanf` reads a value from the standard input into `a`
3. `scanf` returns a value
4. This return value is assigned to `a`.

The final value of `a` is decided by the return value of `scanf`, either 1 (if that one variable `a` was read successfully) or 0 (read failed).

**Edit:**

The answer was written before the question was edited to

`int a = store_and_return_value(&a);`

The same reasoning goes here.