# Recursive dependency of variable and function in global scope

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

I was playing with my C++ compiler and I noticed a recursive dependency of a global variable and a function call is not rejected. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo();

int t = foo();

int foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello before main: " << t << "\n";
    t = 10;
    return t + 10;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello from main.\n";
}
```

This compiled program prints out the following:

```
Hello before main: 0
Hello from main.
```

So when I use declare the `t` it has a dependency on the `foo` function which again has a dependency on `t`. The C++ compiler breaks this loop by essentially having `t` be zero initialized before the assignment expression runs.

This was surprising to me. Is this correct behavior according to the standard or am I invoking some undefined behavior here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Since C++20*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61219932/3309790), the lifetime of object is considered to begin when its initializations finish; before that access to it leads to UB.

[[basic.life]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1):

> ... The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - its initialization (if any) is complete (including vacuous initialization) ...

*Until C++20* this was well-defined behavior. [Zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) is performed at first for [non-local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables).

> As described in [non-local initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables), static and thread-local variables `that aren't constant-initialized (since C++14)` are zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place. If the definition of a non-class non-local variable has no initializer, then default initialization does nothing, leaving the result of the earlier zero-initialization unmodified.

From the standard, [[basic.start.static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2)

> If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration ([[basic.stc.static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.stc.static)) or thread storage duration ([[basic.stc.thread]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.stc.thread)) is zero-initialized ([[dcl.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init)). Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. All static initialization strongly happens before ([[intro.races]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races)) any dynamic initialization.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm not quite sure but does that mean that the lifetime of `t` begins only when all the initializations (including zero-initialization and copy-initialization for this case) finish?

Comment: Currently it reads as that accessing an object before its dynamic initialization is completed is UB, but IIUC this is considered a defect.